# nuget.exe push throws error. The underlying connection was closed: The connection was closed unexpectedly

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, nexus

I have created few nuget packages in a folder and I am trying to publish it to [Nexus](https://www.sonatype.com/nexus-repository-sonatype) from jenkins. Below is my stage code:

```
stage('Publish To Nexus') {
    when {
        branch 'dev'
    }
    steps {
        parallel (
            "Publish Application Packages": {
                script {
                    bat "nuget.exe push \"${PACKAGE_PATH}\\*.nupkg\"  ${NEXUS_APIKEY} -Source \"${FEED_URL}\" -Timeout 36000"
                }
            },
            "Publish Upgrader Packages": {
                script {
                    bat "nuget.exe push \"${PACKAGE_PATH_UPGRADER}\\*.nupkg\" ${NEXUS_APIKEY} -Source \"${FEED_URL}\"  -Timeout 36000"
                }
            }
        )
    }
}
```

However, it fails with error (especially for large file size):

```
An error occurred while sending the request.
The underlying connection was closed: The connection was closed unexpectedly.
```

Point to note : When I execute the commands manually one at a time then it uploads fine. Need help to understand better way or alternate way of uploading packages to nexus via jenkins.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by putting [retry](https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/workflow-basic-steps/#retry) and [timeout](https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/workflow-basic-steps/#timeout-enforce-time-limit).

```
steps {
    script {
        echo "Publishing packages"
        retry(3) {
            timeout(time: 30, unit: 'MINUTES') {
                echo "Publish large file."
                bat "_________"
            }
        }
    }
}
```